# Web Api 404 error The resource cannot be found

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-http

I try to use Web Api for send/get data from server.
WebApiConfig.cs :

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Default",
                            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
    }
```

Globa.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    }
```

Api controller (ServicesController.cs):

```
public class ServicesController : ApiController
{

    public List<TreeMenuItem> LoadMetadata()
    {
        List<TreeMenuItem> itemsMenu = new List<TreeMenuItem>();
        TreeMenuItem dataSource = new TreeMenuItem("1", "DataSources", null);
        itemsMenu.Add(dataSource);
        return itemsMenu;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access api from angularJS controller like bellow:

```
angular.module("App", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"])
.controller('MainController', ["$scope", "$http", MainController]);

function MainController($scope, $http) {
var baseUrl = "Services/LoadMetadata";
var params = {};
$http.post(baseUrl, params)
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.roleList = data.data;
});
}
```

I get error 404 on $http.post for "Services/LoadMetadata"!
I tried some version using route - same error 404.
Any help?

Comment: try registering webapi before routes registration

Comment: great. It's ok now. :-).

Comment: Unfortunately , I cannot mark as answer your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the registration sequence...

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);  
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

register web-api-config before route-config because i guess route-config is meddling with the web-api-config...

also please do consider the standard practice of having all your api calls prefixed with api.

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
```