# Angular JS 2 with MVC 4.5 pressing enter on the url in browser displays 404 page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angular

this is my routing.ts in Angular JS 2 MVC4.5 app

```
                import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
                import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

                import { HomeComponent }      from './components/home/home.component';
                import { CarsComponent }      from './components/cars/cars.component';

                const appRoutes: Routes = [
                    {
                        path: 'home',
                        component: HomeComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'cars',
                        component: CarsComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        redirectTo: '/home',
                        pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                ];

                export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

This works fine , but I press enter on http://localhost:3000/cars

[image]

It will display a 404 error page

[image]

it searches localhost:3000/cars in the server and server does not have this end point how to fix this issue ?

In the server side  server side WebApiConfig

```
                    public static class WebApiConfig
                    {
                        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
                        {
                            // Web API configuration and services

                            // Web API routes
                            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                                name: "DefaultApi",
                                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                            );
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Every request you send from browser are handled by the server.  While you press enter in the address bar, it sends the request to the server. But you don't have a path '/cars' in server. That's why it shows 404 error.

Comment: @ti2005 um looking for a fix for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing module registration sequence on `Application_Start` in `Global.asax` file like this one:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); // this line should be placed on top of all routes
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

The standard routing configuration seems meddling with WebApi routing (probably since `RegisterRoutes` declared first on your issue, it assumes all requests from browser's address bar are HTTP request instead of WebApi), thus your WebApi route `localhost:3000/cars` treated as a GET method for `CarsController` by `RegisterRoutes` module and returning 404 page.

Any suggestions welcome.

Similar problem: [Web Api 404 error The resource cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463080/web-api-404-error-the-resource-cannot-be-found)

Answer (score 0):

This has solved the Issue

```
        <configuration>
          <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
          </system.web>

          <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
              <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </rewrite>
          </system.webServer>

        </configuration>
```

Added this on client's web.config